# Help Formatting Financing Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, finance

Say you put 10,000 into a saving account which has a 3% APR (left alone, the account increases by 3% each year). Assume you withdraw $20 a month from this account to pay for your gym membership, but otherwise leave it alone to accrue interest.

(a) Craft a differential equation which modeling this situation.

(b) Find the general solution for the differential equation in (a).

(c) Use the given initial condition to find a particular solution to the differential equation in (a).

I really only need help with part a, I'm completely fine with actually finding the solutions to differential equations once I have them. I'm just unsure how to start this one.

The question mentions that it increase 3% each year left alone so I'm thinking that means compounding isn't required, I wouldn't know what to do then. So I don't know if I can just have the percent increase and manual withdrawals happening at the same time.

The starting equation I came up with was dP/dt = 0.03P - 240 to relate the two quantities, I'm unsure of this and would appreciate help.

Comment: If t is in units of years then your solution looks fine. This assumes continuous compounding and continuous withdrawal which is typical for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That differential equation you came up with is exactly correct. Don't worry about compounding, that only starts to be a headache when dealing with difference equations.

Comment: Alright thanks, there was no real help or explanations give beforehand and I'm not a huge fan of word problems that can be vague,